# Flask : how to pass variables between html pages app route

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a getvlanconfig.html page with a form that collects information like vlanid and vlannetwork. I want to be able to pass that information over to the page showvlanconfig.html that loads when the form is submitted. 
I am new to Flask and from whatever lookup i could do, I was unable to find out the best way to do it. Also I have taken a look at sessions and I am not sure if that would be my option here.

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, request, redirect


    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def homepage():
      return render_template("index.html")

    @app.route('/getvlanconfig/', methods=["GET","POST"])
    def getvlan():

      try:

          if request.method == "POST":
             getvlanid = request.form['vlanid']
             getvlannetwork = request.form['vlannetwork']

             return redirect(url_for('showvlan'))
      except Exception as e:

             return render_template("vlanconfig.html")


 @app.route('/showvlanconfig', methods=["GET","POST"])
 def showvlan():
      try:          
         getvlanid = ???
         getvlannetwork = ?? 
         return render_template("index.html", vlanid = getvlanid, vlannetwork = getvlannetwork)
      except Exception as e:
         flash(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the session to store data between requests from the same client.

```
from flask import session

def getvlan():
    session['vlanid'] = request.form['vlanid']
    return redirect(url_for('showvlan'))

def showvlan():
    vlanid = session['vlanid']
    ...
```

Use a database (or other external, persistent store) to store data in a more generally accessible sense.